# How can I reuse the terraform output values in another Github action using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

Currently we are mapping manually repos details as below, meaning that we are adding every repos details manually for attribute.repository.

```
workload_identity_pool_attribute_mapping = {
  "google.subject"             = "assertion.sub"
  "attribute.repository"       = <<-EOT
  {
    "example-github-organization/example-repo": "true",
    "example-github-organization/example-repo-1": "true"
  }[assertion.repository]
  EOT
}
```

Now we've requirement that want to reuse below output details into another repo to map the string for GCP workload_identity_pool_attribute_mapping.

as we've a Github repo where we're maintaining our github repos centrally and created Output to save those details into terraform output, as below.

```
{"outputs": {
    "git_repos": {
      "value": [
        "example-repo",
        "example-repo-1",
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Want to reuse those output details as a input for another repos for mapping.

Tried multiple approach to fill the request but not able to not able fulfill the requirement.

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {
    }
    
data "terraform_remote_state" "repo" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket       = var.tfstate_bucket
    prefix       = "example-project"
    access_token = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  }
}
```

Expected result is that if any changes on repos list it has to add newly created repo into attribute.repository.
Here **example-github-organization** is using to same for each repo and all repos name is going to start with **example**.

```
workload_identity_pool_attribute_mapping = {
  "google.subject"             = "assertion.sub"
  "attribute.repository"       = <<-EOT
  {
    "example-github-organization/example-repo": "true",
    "example-github-organization/example-repo-1": "true"
  }[assertion.repository]
  EOT
}
```

*I'm new to terraform please forgive me if i didn't follow the right format*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which will help you add a string into jsonencode

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {
      }
    
data "terraform_remote_state" "repo" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket = var.tfstate_bucket
    prefix = "your-project"
    access_token = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  }
}

locals {
  repos_mapping        = { for repo in data.terraform_remote_state.repo.outputs.git_repos : "your-github-organization/${repo}" => "true" }
  attribute_repository = <<-EOT
    ${jsonencode(local.repos_mapping)}[assertion.repository]
  EOT
}

# Assuming you are applying this mapping in a resource or data source that supports workload_identity_pool_attribute_mapping
resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool" "example" {
  # Other necessary configuration

  workload_identity_pool_attribute_mapping = {
    "google.subject"             = "assertion.sub"
    "attribute.exam_repository" = local.attribute_repository
  }
}
```